# Async/Await for Scala Async framework

Tags: scala, async-await, future

Let's say i have the following Future

```
val fut = Future { ... my expensive computation}
```

does the

```
await(fut)
```

return only when fut has a successful completion?
how does it work if fut fails? will the exception be propagated?

Comment: If you want to try it, these are two possibilities to generate a failed future: `Future.failed(new Exception())` or `Future { new Exception() }`

Comment: @kosii `Future { new Exception() }` will just return a successful `Future[Exception]`.  You need to throw it.

Comment: @Ryan wow, how could I missed that, you are completely right

Comment: @Falmarri Trying isn't a valid verification mechanism, since you still won't know what is guaranteed and what is not. What you have to do instead is RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

Async/await is not yet part of the Scala standard library. You can read more info on it here: [scala-async](https://github.com/scala/async).

"await" can only be used withing a directly enclosing "async" block. An "async" block will return a Future containing the result of the computation it encloses. An "await" will block the computation untill the future it waits for is completed and returns the successful value it contains, or throws the exception it encountered otherwise. It will block indefinetily!

If you wanted to know how to use [scala.concurrent.Await](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await$), you can read a short tutorial on the Blocking section [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).